# Hik-Vision camera output stream is not visible through ivms app and Hi-Connect app?

Tags: camera, hikvision

DVR
Verified DVR (DS-7204HGHI-F1) is working fine and HDD is in good status.
Firmware:  V3.4.89 build 180906
Latest version no upgrade required.
Network
Network configuration is set and no firewall block and DVR public IP is reachable from the outside network
IPv4 public address: Network -> Basic setttings -> TCP/IP -> IPv4 Address

Note:-
Camera output is visible through DVR HDMI output.

does ivms-4200 or Hi-Connect app compatible with DVR DS-7204HGHI-F1 model

Answer (score 0):

Found solution and reason behind.
DVR model DS-7204HGHI-F1 and firmware V3.4.89 build 180906  is not supported by Hi-Connect app as suggested by HiK-Vision DVR but ivms-4200 does support.

To enable ivms-4200 app support, the below DVr configuration to be done.
Network -> Advanced Settings -> Platform Access -> uncheck the Enable box (Platform Access Mode drop down list = HiK-Connect) -> Save.

After the above action now the ivms-4200 app should able to view the output stream from DVR